# Cómo se hace un menú con click derecho en Java?

Tags: java

Estoy haciendo un programa que en el cual me gustaría agregar opciones mediante un menú cuando el usuario haga click derecho como en cualquier otra interfaz de usuario ya que esto no viene por defecto al menos en el IDE que uso (NetBeans).

Comment: Bienvenido a la comunidad, te sugiero leer [ask] y de paso hacer el [tour], nos mostrarías lo que llevas hecho y/o investigado al momento?

Comment: Buenas, ya tienes una respuesta pero te comento una cosa. Según los criterios de usabilidad del software no es recomendable asignar acciones al click derecho en una UI. Aún que supongo que cada cosa tiene su fin al final. Un saludo.

Comment: Agrega el código que tratas de realizar por favor, revisa [ask].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Puedes hacerlo agregando un ActionListener y comprobar los modificadores:

```
boton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        if ((e.getModifiers() & 4) !=0){
             // boton derecho
        }
    }
});
```

Saludos

Tutorial completo no es mio.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=n7dEyk2vEhs